# angular won't display scope variable (done)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, jstree

I'm working with jstree and angularjs. I've got path and name of nodes but cannot display it on a page. Where is my mistake? I have updated [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LyF3DAosCTpBb7SMSpsQ?p=preview)(working) example with ng-tree directive with my problem. Now it's pretty close to my app

also I provide the code of plunker here

Html:

```
 <h1>Where is my variable?!</h1>
         <div>{{ test }}</div>
  <pre>Path to A: {{ pathA }}</pre>
   <pre>Path to B: {{ pathB }}</pre>
      <pre>Path to C:{{ pathC }}</pre>
<js-tree tree-data="json" tree-src="tree.json"
                   tree-events="changed:callback;"></js-tree>
```

Js

```
$scope.test = "I'm test variable"

    $scope.callback = function (e, data) {

        // ===== Click event on node for Industry =====
        for (var i = 0; i < data.selected.length; i++) {

            var parentNodeId = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).parent;
            var parentNodeText = data.instance.get_node(parentNodeId).text;
            var selectedNodes = data.instance.get_selected();

            var node = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i]).text;

            console.log(node);

            if (node == "a"){
                     console.log($scope.pathA)
             $scope.pathA  = data.instance.get_path(data.node,'/');

            }
             else if (node == "b"){
                 console.log($scope.pathA)
              $scope.pathB  = data.instance.get_path(data.node,'/');

            }
             else if (node == "c"){
               console.log($scope.pathA)
             $scope.pathC  = data.instance.get_path(data.node,'/');

            }
            // and etc....
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery in such way with angular..you should really [thing of to switch to angular version of js-tree](https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree)

Comment: @PankajParkar, I'm using [another js-tree angular directive](https://github.com/arvindr21/jsTree-directive) in app, I've provided just simple example

Comment: your code were showing jQuery version of it only. and nothing were implemented using it.

Comment: @PankajParkar, please wait a couple minutes I'll rewrite sample

Comment: @PankajParkar I have updated plunker, check it please

Comment: `$scope.pathA;` This won't do anything. Did you maybe mean `return $scope.pathA;`?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz even you will try 'return it', this also won't do anything

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz I'm trying to display path to child node when I click on it

Comment: It works for me, but only on double click

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz Does it show you path of child node on a page under title "Where is my variable?". Note, not in console

Comment: works for me with double click as well. I'm seeing: jk -> Data Standards -> a, b, c in bullets

Comment: @water42 you have to see the path over the tree, like this "jk/Data Standards/a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jstree` isn't causing any change detection, which means that the callback won't either and none of your variables will get updated. You can fix this by manually calling `$scope.$apply()` in the callback!